# Not able to upload json data to Bigquery tables using c#

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to upload json data to one of the table created under the dataset in Bigquery but fails with "Google.GoogleApiException: 'Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Not found: Table currency-342912:sampleDataset.currencyTable  [404]"

1. Service account is created with roles BigQuery.Admin/DataEditor/DataOwner/DataViewer.
2. The roles are also applied to the table also.

Below is the snippet

```
public static void LoadTableGcsJson(string projectId = "currency-342912", string datasetId = "sampleDataset", string tableId= "currencyTable ")
    {
//Read the Serviceaccount key json file
        string dir = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName + "\\" + "currency-342912-ae9b22f23a36.json";
        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(dir);
        string toFileName = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName + "\\" + "sample.json";
        BigQueryClient client = BigQueryClient.Create(projectId,credential);
        var dataset = client.GetDataset(datasetId);

        using (FileStream stream = File.Open(toFileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            // Create and run job
            BigQueryJob loadJob = client.UploadJson(datasetId, tableId, null, stream); //This throws error
            loadJob.PollUntilCompleted();
        }
       
    }
```

Permissions for the table, using the service account "sampleservicenew" from the screenshot
[image]

Any leads on this , much appreciated

Comment: I found a [load sample](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#loading_json_data_into_a_new_table) but its a bit different from your code. Have you try performing the operation with a dummy table to check privileges, json structure?? what version of your library are you using??. Are you passing the correct elements to uploadjson?

Comment: ref [upload json](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/latest/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.BigQueryClient#Google_Cloud_BigQuery_V2_BigQueryClient_UploadJson_Google_Apis_Bigquery_v2_Data_TableReference_Google_Apis_Bigquery_v2_Data_TableSchema_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__Google_Cloud_BigQuery_V2_UploadJsonOptions_) documentation.

Comment: @Betjens I have gone through the documentation , seems i am doing everything correct.

below is the Data present in  my json file 


{"IsFee":false,"BlockDateTime":"2018-09-11T00:12:14Z","Address":"tz3UoffC7FG7zfpmvmjUmUeAaHvzdcUvAj6r","BlockHeight":98304,"Type":"OUT","Value":1}
{"IsFee":false,"BlockDateTime":"2018-09-11T00:12:14Z","Address":"tz2KuCcKSyMzs8wRJXzjqoHgojPkSUem8ZBS","BlockHeight":98304,"Type":"IN","Value":18}

Schema  of the table : matches with the json data being passed

Library used and version - Google.Cloud.BigQuery.v2(2.3.0)

The json is present in new lines

Comment: Hello Debasish22, I added a response, have you manage to make it work?

Comment: @Betjens i have still the same issue . I did follow the steps except the one below 

Please check if the user you are using to execute your application have access to the table you want to insert data.

Can you please help me with this to check

Comment: @Betjens Ran  the below command 

gcloud projects get-iam-policy currency-342912

The user has roles of  editor, owner , viewer,browser, bigquery.jobuser/dataviewer/dataowner/editor/admin

Comment: Ok, but does he have access to load that specific table? (The table you are trying to load are located in the same project your user have access??) The user I use for my code its owner and Its inside a dataset of the same project. When running my code, what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might reside in your user credentials. Please follow this steps to check your code:

- Please check if the user you are using to execute your application have access to the table you want to insert data.
- If your json tags matchs your table columns.
- If you json inputs are correct ( table name, dataset name ).
- Use a dummy table to perform a quick test of your credentials and data integrity.

These steps will help you identifying what could be missing on your side. I perform the following operations to reproduce your case:

- I created a table on BigQuery based on the values of your json data:

```
create or replace table `projectid.datasetid.tableid` (
    IsFee BOOL,
    BlockDateTime timestamp,
    Address STRING,
    BlockHeight INT64,
    Type STRING,
    Value INT64
);
```

- Created a `.json` file with your test data

```
{"IsFee":false,"BlockDateTime":"2018-09-11T00:12:14Z","Address":"tz3UoffC7FG7zfpmvmjUmUeAaHvzdcUvAj6r","BlockHeight":98304,"Type":"OUT","Value":1}
{"IsFee":false,"BlockDateTime":"2018-09-11T00:12:14Z","Address":"tz2KuCcKSyMzs8wRJXzjqoHgojPkSUem8ZBS","BlockHeight":98304,"Type":"IN","Value":18}
```

- Build & Run below code.

```
using System;
using Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2;   
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using System.IO;

namespace stackoverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            String projectid = "projectid";
            String datasetid = "datasetid";
            String tableid = "tableid";
            String safilepath ="credentials.json";

            var credentials = GoogleCredential.FromFile(safilepath); 
            BigQueryClient client = BigQueryClient.Create(projectid,credentials); 
           
            using (FileStream stream = File.Open("data.json", FileMode.Open))
            {
                BigQueryJob loadJob = client.UploadJson(datasetid, tableid, null, stream);
                loadJob.PollUntilCompleted();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- output

| **Row** | **IsFee** | **BlockDateTime** | **Address** | **BlockHeight** | **Type** | **value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | false | 2018-09-11 00:12:14 UTC | tz3UoffC7FG7zfpmvmjUmUeAaHvzdcUvAj6r | 98304 | OUT | 1 |
| 2 | false | 2018-09-11 00:12:14 UTC | tz2KuCcKSyMzs8wRJXzjqoHgojPkSUem8ZBS | 98304 | IN | 18 |

**Note**: You can use above code to perform your quick tests of your credentials and the integrity of the data to insert.

I also make use of the following documentation:

- [Load Credentials from a file](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file#loading_credentials_from_a_file)
- [Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/latest)
- [Load Json data into a new table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#loading_json_data_into_a_new_table)